# Non browser JS library

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-mobile

I'm using Appcelerator Titanium but I want a good JS library to help with object and array manipulation.

A cut down version of dojo or jQuery with out references to window, navigator or the DOM would be good.

Many thanks.

Can anyone suggest one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) has a lot of useful features not strictly related to the DOM.

Comment: Yep, +1 for Underscore. It's one of those libraries I've ended up using in pretty much all JavaScript (and even more so, CoffeeScript (by the same author, btw)) projects nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Try [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)